# Creating DotPlots

Tags: plotting

I've been struggling to create a DotPlot like the one shown in Cleveland's [The Elements of Graphing Data.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0963488414)

[image]

Using the following dataset

```
data = Sort[{#, 
 WolframAlpha[
  StringJoin["Number of native speakers ", #], {{"Result", 1}, 
   "ComputableData"}]} & /@ {"Mandarin", "French", "English", 
"Spanish", "German", "Hindi", "Malay", "Arabic", "Portuguese", 
"Russian", "Korean", "Italian", "Cantonese", "Telugu", 
"Urdu"}, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
```

What is the best approach to replicate this chart with its two axis, dot, dashed lines , etc?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this :

```
data = Sort[{#, 
  WolframAlpha[
   StringJoin["Number of native speakers ", #], {{"Result", 1}, 
   "ComputableData"}]} & /@ {"Mandarin", "French", "English", 
   "Spanish", "German", "Hindi", "Malay", "Arabic", "Portuguese", 
   "Russian", "Korean", "Italian", "Cantonese", "Telugu", 
   "Urdu"}, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]

sorted = SortBy[data, #[[2]] &] ;
len= Length[sorted] ;

ListPlot[Transpose[{Log[2, sorted[[All, 2]]/10^6], Range[len]}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, sorted[[#, 1]]} & /@ Range[len], None}, {{#, 2^#} & /@ Range[len], {#, #} & /@ Range[len]}},
 GridLines -> {None, {#, Dotted} & /@ Range[len]},
 FrameLabel -> {"Number of Speakers (millions)", ""}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Log Number of Speakers (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(2\)]\) \ \ millions)", 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, Log[2, 1.5]}]
```

[image: data]

Comment: you just need the top ticks and you're all set. Use a frame with the 4 element list version for the ticks

Comment: @R.M Thanks, I totally overlooked that.

Comment: speakers are now stored in "people" units so You need `sorted = MapAt[QuantityMagnitude, #, {2}] & /@ SortBy[data, #[[2]] &]` but I'm not very familiar with `Units` so maybe it could be done simpler.

Answer (score 14):

Except for the simplest graphics, you almost always have more flexibility and control if you build the graphics expressions bottom-up, eg try a variation on this:

```
Graphics[
 {{Opacity[0.3], Dashed, Line[{{0, First@#2}, {900, First@#2}}]}, 
    Text[First@#, {0, First@#2}, {1, 0}],
    Blue, Disk[{Last@#/10^6, First@#2}, 5*{1, 0.03}]} &~ MapIndexed~ 
  data,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Frame -> {True, False, False, False},
 BaseStyle -> FontFamily -> "Helvetica"
 ]
```

Note there's some hacks here (bad programming practice, but faster to implement):

- The '900' as parameter to `Line` instead of extracting the Max coordinate
- The 5*{1,0.03} as parameter to `Disk` (effecting ellipses) which must be tuned to `AspectRatio`, instead of using `Epilog` and `Inset` to decouple from `AspectRatio`. I've bugged WRI about this 'feature'.

[image]

Comment: If you use `Point` (with either `PointSize` or `AbsolutePointSize`) instead of `Disk` you don't have to worry about aspect ratios.

Comment: That works for simple elements like Point and Line, but doesn't work for most other icons, eg, if you want a Rectangle, a Star, or any other shape-coded elements which are common in visualization nowadays. Do you know of a way to avoid Epilog?

Comment: `Inset` is one possibility:

Comment: `star = Graphics[
  Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi (2 i + 1)/5], Sin[2 Pi (2 i + 1)/5]}, {i, 
     5}]]]`

Comment: `Graphics[Table[
  Inset[star, RandomReal[1, 2], Center, Offset[25]], {20}], 
 AspectRatio -> 2]`

Comment: Thanks Brett, that works modulo Color in the above graphic, substituting for Disk --> Inset[star, {Last@#/10^6, First@#2}, Center, Offset[10]]. It appear Offset with one parameter controls the star's size; wasn't aware of this behavior. However, the stars are rendered black, not blue. If {Blue,star} are passed to Inset, the result is some weird blue paw-mark looking icons. Any clues?

Comment: This is getting beyond the scope of a comment...  You need to get the `Blue` inside `star` (which is a complete graphic, not just a polygon.)

Comment: That works. I'm pushing WRI to provide a more orthogonal solution to this problem. It should be possible to specify Color or other modifiers to a sequence of graphics elements whether Inset or not.

Answer (score 7):

It is a `Chart` so one may want to use `BarChart`:

```
(* speakers are stored with [people] units so we have to get rid of it, 
   I'm also deleting Malavian since there is no data now*)
sorted = MapAt[QuantityMagnitude, #, {2}] & /@SortBy[data, #[[2]] &] // Rest
len = Length[sorted]

mark[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := {Black, AbsolutePointSize@7, 
                                              Point[{Scaled[{0, -.02}, {xmax, ymax}]}]}
topt = Table[{i, 2^i}, {i, 0, 9}];

BarChart[Log[2, sorted[[ ;; , 2]]/10^6], 
         ChartLabels -> sorted[[ ;; , 1]], BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> Large, 
         GridLines -> {None, Range@len}, GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, 
         ChartElementFunction -> mark, Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, True}},
         AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, FrameTicks -> {{False, False}, {Automatic, topt}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm not seeing the chart labels.  (Version 11.1.)  As far as I can tell, the `Frame` option cannot be used if we want the label to show.  (Bug?)

Comment: @Alan will try to find some time later to check.

Comment: If the left-spine frame ticks are set to `Automatic`, then with `Frame->True` the labels appear and actually looks nice, imo.