# Reversing Plot Axis with scientific Notation

Tags: plotting

I'm dealing now with a problem of three steps which already has solutions in each of them. Basically, I want to write numbers on  x-axis with scientific notation, but before that, I reverse the axis following this [reversing plot axis for Plot, LogPlot, LogLogPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107370/reversing-plot-axis-for-plot-logplot-loglogplot?rq=1), afterwards I add a new scale with a function relating two time scales (the x axis) following [How to make plot with frame and two different scales on the x-axis (CMB power spectrum example)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19639/how-to-make-plot-with-frame-and-two-different-scales-on-the-x-axis-cmb-power-sp)

1. So first of all I defined two functions, the first one to properly reverse the plot, and the second one which give the rescaling in the axis

   ```
    ze[t_] = 10^(9)*Exp[0.68 - t] - 1;
    zp[t_] = -t + 25;
   ```

lets plot an arbitrary function (in my case is the solution of  a system of 5 coupled ODE's)

```
    Needs["MaTeX`"]

    fx[t_] = 3 t - Exp[t + 2];

    Plot1 = Plot[fx[zp[t]], {t, 0, 25}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red, DotDashed]}, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> {(MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 2.6] &) /@ 
    Style["\\mathcal{T}"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
    FrameStyle -> BlackFrame, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 15
    },
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{
  Directive[Thick, Red, DotDashed]}, {
  (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 1.6] &) /@ Style["f_x"]},
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, 
 LegendFunction -> Frame],
{0.46, 0.28}], ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
 None}, {Transpose[{Range[0, 25, 5], 
   N@ze[#] & /@ Range[0, 25, 5]}], Range[0, 25, 5]}}]
```

[image: Plot1]

(the gray comes from the style I'm using on the notebook). This plot then is inverted in the axis (by function zp[t]) and with and additional scale. So my problem is to put that ugly horizontal scale (reescaled by the function ze[t]) in scientific notation. I tried to used CustomTicks, but perhaps I'm missing something. Appreciate any help

Comment: does `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,  None}, {Transpose[{Range[0, 25, 5], 
     ScientificForm[ze[#], 2] & /@ Range[0, 25, 5]}],  Range[0, 25, 5]}}` give what you need?

Comment: Dear @kglr, thanks a lot... this is almost what I want (maybe I should clarify that) Or maybe I'm adding an innecesary step. Can I just represent that scale in sort of Logaritmic one? Actualy the plot I need (with my calculations) should be LogLinearPlot.

Comment: you mean something like this: `LogLinearPlot[fx[zp@Exp[t]], {t, 1, Log@25}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red, DotDashed]}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]`?

Comment: or `Plot[fx[t], {t, 0, 25},  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red, DotDashed]}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1,  
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}]`?