# How to control the default date interval in the DateListPlot?

Tags: date-and-time

I am trying to plot a time series data using the DateLisPlot. While the plot comes out fine, Mathematica is choosing the default date interval as Months. My data set contains the data at  the granularity of days and I want tot control the interval at which the data is plotted. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am attaching an image of my current plot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Post your Mathematica code, not just picture.

Comment: Sorry for the oversight. My code goes as follows `code` DateListPlot[{indiaCases, usaCases}]`code`. indiaCases and usaCases are two associations containing the date  as the key and the count as the value.

Comment: You can use FrameTicks as per [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39453/datelistplot-show-all-the-dates-in-ticks) answer.